# Removing EventListeners in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a function in which I want to remove an `EventListener`, but it gives me the following error:

```
Access of undefined property event
```

Here is the code in question:

```
dr_line.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,drawln);
var test:Boolean;

function drawln(e:MouseEvent):void{
    event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, drawln);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,click1);    
}

var sx,sy,fx,fy,j:int;

function click1(e:MouseEvent):void{
    sx=mouseX;
    sy=mouseY;
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,click2);
}

function click2(e:MouseEvent):void{
    var i:int;
    i=1;
    trace(i);
    fx=mouseX;
    fy=mouseY;
    var  line:Shape = new Shape();
    line.graphics.beginFill(0x00FF00);
    line.graphics.moveTo(sx,sy);
    line.graphics.lineTo(fx,fy);
    this.addChild(line);
}
```

I tried doing the same removal of the event listener in `click1` and `click2`, but it still doesn`t work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

event is not declared; e is.  Try changing this:

```
function drawln(e:MouseEvent):void{
    event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, drawln);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,click1);    
}
```

to this:

```
function drawln(e:MouseEvent):void{
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, drawln);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,click1);    
}
```

or possibly even this:

```
function drawln(e:MouseEvent):void{
    dr_line.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, drawln);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,click1);    
}
```